# Text is not showing in android textview?

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a simple layout and the java class which have to update a textview. For whatever reason, the text is not being shown. I have checked the variable, it certainly has the value to be displayed. Only the textview is not being updated in the UI.

```
public class PlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener, AdListener{

    // create string variables
    String YOUTUBE_APIKEY;
    String ID, Title;
    private TextView titleview;

    private InterstitialAd interstitial;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "LayarTancep";

    // create object of view
    YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);


        // connect view object and view id on xml
        youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);

        titleview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // create the interstitial
        interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, getString(R.string.admob_id));

        // load interstitialAd
        Ads.loadInterstitialAd(interstitial);

        // set Ad Listener to use the callbacks below
        interstitial.setAdListener(this);

        // get YOUTUBE APIKEY
        YOUTUBE_APIKEY = getString(R.string.youtube_apikey);

        // get video id from previous page
        Intent i = getIntent();
        ID = i.getStringExtra("id");
        Title = i.getStringExtra("title");


        titleview.setText(Title);

        Log.i("TESTING", Title);

    }
}
```

Here is the layout file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >



        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />




    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="142dp" >
    </com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why you create two `titleview  Object`?

Comment: As MD says, you shouldn't be creating a new textview.  Cut out that line, and just use the one from findViewById.

Comment: i removed the second textview...and it is still not displaying the text.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ...
    //titleview = new TextView(PlayerActivity.this); remove this line 
    titleview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    ...
```

You dont have to create a new TextView Object as you are referencing to the one already defined in the layout file.

Comment: What value does the logcat display?

Comment: it displays the text which i intend to display on the textview. Could there be a problem in my layout file?

Comment: i tested with a static text on setText..that does not show up...so im guessing the problem is in the layout.

Comment: Is "larget text" visible initially?

Comment: Have you tried debigging the code ? The reason may be totally different

Answer (score 0):

just remove titleview = new TextView(PlayerActivity.this); and it would work perfectly